# How to add text to chart.js data?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I need help to add a text after the data that shows the graph, the code I have is the following:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'pie',
          data: {
          labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"],
          datasets: [{
            data: [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ]
          }]
        }
      }
```

It shows me the information like this:

> label1: 10

But i need to add text after that, something like:

> label1: 10 Mb

Please, I don't know how to add it, I already tried several ways

Answer (score 1):

**Try using this script**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area");
              var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                  type: 'pie',
                  data: {
                      labels: ["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"],
                      datasets: [
                          { data: [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ] }
                      ]
                  },
               options: {
                  tooltips: {
                  enabled: true,
                  callbacks: {
                  label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                      var val = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                      return label + ' : ' + val + ' Mb';
                  }
                }
              }
            }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

ChartJs does not provide any format label feature you have to play with it.
Initialize chart configuration with empty array then update it when you pushing data.

From this reference  https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2738

here is fiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/qsnpsxz5/7/

```
chart.config.data.labels.push("A label");
chart.config.data.labels.push("A label2");
chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push(10);
chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.push(20);
chart.update();
```